# Random ThreadAbortException on Asp.Net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, threadabortexception

I have ThreadAbortException randomly (loop on same HTTP request for testing) when debugging, I don't know why...
It appears after a few minutes requesting.

The stacktrace :

```
  at System.AppDomain.nUnload(Int32 domainInternal)
  at System.AppDomain.Unload(AppDomain domain)
```

I don't use Response.End, Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer (reference to https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/troubleshoot/aspnet/threadabortexception-occurs-you-use-response-end)

What is the reason ??

Comment: At least show us your code please. If enough people take a guess, one will get it right eventually, but being able to reproduce it, makes it easier.

Comment: I have no code to show (see the complete stacktrace on my initial post)

Comment: app-domain unload doesn't happen at the request level; it happens either because the server is shutting down, or because it wants to completely reset things periodically due to app pool recycling, perhaps because it thinks the app is misbehaving; are your requests perhaps taking so long that the system thinks the server is borked?

Comment: @MarcGravell My loop request (and only request used for my test) take 600ms. I execute the website with IIS express via visual studio.

Comment: @k4st0r42 all I can say without code is: "that's unexpected"

Comment: @k4st0r42 You mentioned this happens `when debugging`. Do you have execution paused (e.g. because you hit a breakpoint) for a considerable period of time (e.g. 30 seconds or longer)?

Comment: @RB. No breakpoints...